# Is this question closeworthy?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, question-quality

So I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967499/using-apis-in-microsoft-visual-studio) question today and was suprised to see it with three upvotes and two upvoted answers. Initially I edited the question because it was confusing the IDE (Visual Studio) for the actual framework (Xamarin)

Basically, the OP is new to the technology and is basically asking *How do I call an API with [technology]*, which to me seems like without much information, could be flagged as too broad. Furthermore it appears that there's been little research attempt as Googling *"how to call an API with Xamarin"* brings plenty of results, the first link with a few coed examples and tutorials. The OP includes code, but it appears to be fresh template code and hasn't seem to give any attempt.

Am I right to give this a close flag? Or is the question fine as is? It did get three upvotes, but that could be luck.

Comment: _give this a flag_ which flag are you referring to? Close flag?

Comment: @SurajRao yes, a close flag

Comment: Also, please be careful of the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) when asking a question like this... Are you asking if it is closeworthy?

Comment: @SurajRao yes, mainly because it has been upvoted and attracted a couple answers though

Comment: Personally, I agree it looks _too broad_. I also find it unusual that it already accrued 4 up-votes... but life has its share of mysteries.

Comment: There is no point in trying to understand (up/down)voting. Probably [Tim lost some more keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/388562).

Comment: There is no mysteries, low rep user have their own rule and use upvote as acknowledgment notification. It simply mean, "I have read your question, please read my answer", or "I have read your answer , please read my comment, I have an other issue". This way User have a yellow Arrow to know what they have read on a question.

Comment: reasons for all upvotes are fairly easy to guess by checking rep history of involved users and paying attention on when respective rep events happened. Two first upvotes to question occurred when answers were posted, these are most likely from answerers ("I can answer it meaning it's good"). An hour later third upvote was cast, possibly by some user who thought that score +2 indicates good question and joined the bandwagon. After that rep of the asker has got over 15 meaning they gained privilege to upvote and at this time both answers got upvotes, likely from grateful asker

Comment: ^^^ @DragandDrop timing of upvotes seems to support your explanation :)

Comment: @AndréKool  You're specifically contradicting the post that you're linking to.  Tim is not saying that there is no point in trying to understand votes, and that you should always ignore them.  Tim simply says that *sometimes*, after trying to figure out what a vote is signifying, you will be unable to do so, and sometimes, *on occasion*, there isn't meaning to be divined.  That doesn't mean you never try, it just means that you won't always be successful in your attempts to figure out how to improve a post based on downvotes.  That you won't always succeed doesn't mean you shouldn't try.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This needs to be closed. Let's dissect it and learn why

> I have been given a task to made a coding project using at least two APIs from a company

We're not off to a great start. People describing broad (and basic) project goals are typically unfamiliar with coding, projects, etc. It's not a deal breaker, but a caution flag. Let's read on (emphasis mine)

> I've decided to use the APN Products and APN Categories to build something simple. Maybe an app that lets you find out how many products you have in what category. **But I don't really know how to get started.** I just recently graduated with a degree in IT, but I've never learned about or used APIs, so I'm a little confused.

Yikes. We just went from bad to worse. It's not relevant how much coding you know. Saying so is often an excuse for asking a bad question ("I'm a newbie, please help me!"). But maybe I'm wrong. Let's read on

> I'm using Xamarin Android (C#) to build the app. **I think I need to also use javascript in the app to get the API's to work, but again I'm not sure how**. I appreciate any and all advice the community can give me. **I'll post the code that Visual Studio provides me as a starting template in case it will help someone give me good advice on what to do.**

And there it is. The OP doesn't know where to start but they posted up **sample code from Visual Studio** (we need a facepalm emoji for this). The people who upvoted this didn't read any of it ("He asked a question! With code! How brave!"). If you disregard the code block (which the OP just told us we could), the problems with the question become much clearer.

So we can close this as *Too Broad* or lacking [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Either works.

Comment: I agree with too broad, but I don't think lacking MCVE applies very well here. I can't think of how you'd create an MCVE for "I don't really know how to get started."

Comment: _«The people who upvoted this didn't read any of it ("He asked a question! With code! How brave!")»_ So much this.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: That's exactly the point.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well yeah, I get that "impossible to create MCVE for this problem" means that it's lacking an MCVE by definition, but I thought MCVE was intended to illustrate a problem you're having with some code you wrote, not with some code you don't know how to write.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: Right, and if you don't have any code yet, because you don't know how to write it, then you're in the wrong place! Stack Overflow is not for mentoring/teaching/tutoring. Other websites and real-world resources (school? library? colleague?) exist for that. That is why this question is off-topic. "Doesn't have an MCVE because OP didn't write one", and "Doesn't have an MCVE because it is impossible to create one for this kind of off-topic question" both feed into the MCVE close vote reason quite nicely, I think is what Machavity is trying to say.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Agree to agree.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Normally I roll with *Too Broad* on questions without code. But in this case, we got code that was raw dumped into the question. So if you're going to dump code, that puts MCVE into play for me.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: lol :P